# Ticks in ListLogPlot using LevelScheme

Tags: ticks, levelscheme

I am using for the first time the package LevelScheme and I don't succeed in ploting the ticks of the logaritmic vertical scale. Anyone with the same problem? I post an example of the problem:

```
ListLogPlot[{{{0.049999999999999996`, 
    6.80342021478184`}, {20.000000000000068`, 
    0.6797510625196234`}}, {{0.049999999999999996`, 
    6.851041750035086`}, {20.000000000000068`, 
    734391.1255889923`}}, {{0.049999999999999996`, 
    6.854580160605345`}, {20.`, 
    6.854580160605345`}}, {{0.049999999999999996`, 
    1.058498594291096`*^-8}, {20.000000000000068`, 
    0.6774391003463082`}}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0.01, 1000000}}, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[2.5], 
    Darker[Opacity[1, Blue], 0.15]}, {AbsoluteThickness[2.5], 
    Darker[Opacity[1, Red], 0.15]}, {Dotted, AbsoluteThickness[2.5], 
    Lighter[Opacity[0.75, Gray], 0.15]}, {Dashed, 
    AbsoluteThickness[2.5], Lighter[Opacity[0.75, Black], 0.15]}}, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Darker[Opacity[1, Blue], 0.15], 
   Point[{4.099999999999999, Log[3.1337978336706916]}]}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1.5]], 
 FrameTicks -> {LinTicks[0, 20], LogTicks[10, -2, 6], None, None}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, 28, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", Black, 28, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"],
    Style["y", Black, 28, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, 28, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{120, 20}, {90, 20}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Placed[
    LineLegend[{Style["A", Black, 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"],
       Style["B", Black, 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"], 
      Style["C", Black, 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"], 
      Style["D", Black, 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"]}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 30}], {0.25, 0.75}], 
   Placed[PointLegend[{Style["Point", Black, 20, 
       FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"]}, 
     LegendMarkers -> "\[FilledCircle]", 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 30}], {0.25, 0.75}]}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post a small self contained snippet of code demonstrating your problem.

Comment: If you're just starting out with LevelScheme, take a look at SciDraw instead which is the successor of LevelScheme.  The best solution depends on what exactly you are trying to plot ...

Comment: Plus the documentation is really extensive

Comment: I can't reproduce this even using the oldest available version of the `CustomTicks.m` file I can find.